# PhpStorm - associate SQL schema with project source

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm reports Unresolved reference errors for SQL
statements in source code editor:

> Unable to resolve column `expiry_time`
>
> Inspection info: This
> inspection performs unresolved SQL references check

There is a MySQL schema file for the project, but I can't find how to associate this schema file with the project source.

Clicking on the red lightbulb on the left hand side enables creating a new table but can't see how to import an existing table definition.

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, AFAIK you need to create new Data Source .. but instead of real DB you point to your DDL file (schema file). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/connecting-to-a-database.html#create_ddl_data_source

Comment: Thanks, from Data Source Properties icon have now registered DDL data source. Would you care to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new Data Source in Database toolwindow and point to your database (be it dev version or maybe even a live one).

If using an actual database is not possible for whatever reason (specific environment requirements/restrictions or whatnot) but you have schema file, sill create a Data Source but point to your DDL/schema file instead.

See this page for exact steps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/connecting-to-a-database.html#create_ddl_data_source